# Substrate mock error the trait bound `Test: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, substrate

I have created a pallet in Substrate node template and trying to create mocks

Already created the implementation for Config as follows

```
impl frame_system::pallet::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = Everything;
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = u64;
    type BlockNumber = BlockNumber;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Header = Header;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    type DbWeight = ();
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = SS58Prefix;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}
```

But I am getting errors as `^ the trait` frame_system::pallet::Config`is not implemented for`Test  which is already implemented. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: please use https://substrate.stackexchange.com. As it will help it go public. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happened due to a version update on Substrate  Polkadot Version and Closing

Comment: I'd encourage you to ask on the dedicated site for new questions: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/